# No route matches {:controller=>"submissions"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I get this error when I'm running a test that simply does `get :index`. Here is the test code:

```
class SubmissionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @submission = submissions(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :redirect
    # assert_not_nil assigns(:submissions)
  end
```

I have a route set up for this controller though in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :courses do
    resources :assignments do
      get 'export', :controller => 'assignments', :action => 'export'
      resources :memberships
      resources :submissions do
        resources :evaluations do
          delete 'destroy', controller: 'reviews', action: 'destroy'
        end
      end

      resources :questions do
        resources :responses
        resources :scales
      end

      resources :reviews do
        get :assign_reviews, :on => :collection
        post :edit_review, :on => :collection
      end

    end
  end
```

Also, this is what I get for submissions routes when I run rake routes:

```
course_assignment_submissions GET    /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions(.:format)  submissions#index
POST /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions(.:format)  submissions#create
new_course_assignment_submission GET    /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/new(.:format)  submissions#new
edit_course_assignment_submission GET    /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:id/edit(.:format)  submissions#edit
course_assignment_submission GET    /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:id(.:format)  submissions#show
PUT /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:id(.:format)  submissions#update
DELETE /courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:id(.:format)  submissions#destroy
```

And here is my code for the index action:

```
def index
    if !current_user.instructor?(@course)
      raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new("Not authorized!")
    end

    registrations =  @course.registrations
    @students = registrations.select{|r| !r.user.pseudo or @assignment.memberships.any?{|m| m.pseudo_user_id == r.user_id }  }.map{|r| r.user }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @students }
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know where this error could be coming from then?

Comment: Can you add your test code?

Comment: just added my test code

Comment: Can you include the class of your test code (for example, `class SubmissionsController < ActiveSupport::TestCase`)? Also, it looks as though you're missing an `end` at the end of your `assignments` block in `routes.rb`.

Comment: the class is: CoursesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase and thats not my entire routes.rb file I just included up to the submissions routes

Comment: You not including the top of the classes with the name of your test and missing an end in routes or wrong intentions is really hurting our chances of helping you. You haven't even included the index action of the controller in question.

Comment: @MilesStanfield just added the code you mentioned sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Because your `submissions` controller is nested into `assignments` and `assignments` into `courses` you have to pass an `:assignment_id` and a `:course_id` into your get request.

So for example:

```
get :index, course_id: your_course, assignment_id: your_assignment
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:assignment_id=>"1", :controller=>"submissions"}. Also, I don't think this is the problem because my memberships route is defined the same way and the get :index test for that controller passes

Comment: I've updated the answer. OK this sounds odd because your routes must somehow get the IDs.